# Force browser to re-render

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 9 and ngx-Graph I am running into a problem where the graph is not being re-rendered after completing a command to pan to a specific node. It´s only when I move the mouse that the graph get´s rendered. I assume this is a general rendering problem so I wanted to check if there is a way to force the browser to re-render the page without refreshing the url?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer?

Comment: force change detection manualy, by importing ChangeDetectorRef and running its method detectChanges() whenever you want to see changes. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried ChangeDetectorRef without success so I assume this is specific to the graph component. What did work was to simulate the mousemove event like so (not the nicest fix but it works):

```
@ViewChild('graph', { read: ElementRef }) graph:ElementRef;

 private mouseMoveEvent = new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
    clientX: 0,
    clientY: 0,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });

  public panToNode(id: any) {
    this.panToNodeObservable.next(id);
    //  Fix to re-render graph on panning
    this.graph.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(this.mouseMoveEvent);
  }
```